# Reasked/rewrote my question over a year ago but still banned

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

How can I get unbanned? it seems crazy that I can not ask questions on the serverfault site when I have a positive rep overall.

Comment: Reputation doesn't go less than 1. And downvotes that would have taken you lower than 1 are ignored. Without looking your 13 could be the result of -100000 followed by +12.

Answer (score 3):

You're unblocked. Be warned that you're only 1 downvote away from being block again. So use the "Ask Question" button wisely.

Comment: Thank you, I will do my best.